# Understanding Webpack Config: Multiple Entry Points

Tags: webpack

I am looking into this open-source project called Apache Superset.
Since I want to contribute to its frontend, I am trying to understand how its frontend components come together and form an application.

I only have a shallow knowledge in Webpack, but I know it's a good starting point to understand how the frontend components work together.

In the Webpack configuration file of this project (https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/webpack.config.js),

```
const config = {
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  entry: {
    theme: path.join(APP_DIR, '/src/theme.ts'),
    preamble: PREAMBLE,
    addSlice: addPreamble('/src/addSlice/index.tsx'),
    explore: addPreamble('/src/explore/index.jsx'),
    dashboard: addPreamble('/src/dashboard/index.jsx'),
    sqllab: addPreamble('/src/SqlLab/index.tsx'),
    crudViews: addPreamble('/src/views/index.tsx'),
    menu: addPreamble('src/views/menu.tsx'),
    profile: addPreamble('/src/profile/index.tsx'),
    showSavedQuery: [path.join(APP_DIR, '/src/showSavedQuery/index.jsx')],
  },
....
```

I see that there are multiple entry points wrapped with some helper function called `addPreamble`.

First of all, I am not sure how this app works when there are multiple entry points. With my very basic knowledge, I thought Webpack is for creating one single bundle to make the project simpler to get loaded. How would it work if it has multiple entry points?

Second, I am not sure why we need that `addPreamble` function to wrap the location of the modules. What does it do and what is the significance of it?

It was hard to find documentation for this project, so it would be great if anyone could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With multiple entry points, webpack will output multiple bundles, not just a single one. And the HTML page can load just the one it needs or even all the bundles depending on your use case.

Regarding the `addPreamble` function, as you can see from the source code here https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/webpack.config.js#L159, it's a simple function returning an array. In webpack, you can pass [multiple modules to entry](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry), e.g.:

```
entry: {
  vendors: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  main: ['./src/a.js', './src/b.js']
}
```

And that's what `addPreamble` does from what I can tell.

Comment: Thanks. In this project, each of the modules that are used in the entry points represents the entry point to a React project. I am not quite familiar with this structure. It feels like it's pointing to multiple apps that are separate. Do you think you can comment on this?

Comment: Seems you are right here, we can find all those entries having their own `App`, for instance, https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/src/explore/index.jsx#L44, https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/src/addSlice/index.tsx#L23

Comment: Do you know the significance of such a design? Why would we do this usually?

Comment: It depends on your use case and your preference, I don't think there's one-size-fits-all design.